# Percentages work differently than pixels (after using percentages, elements overlap)

Tags: html, css

I try to use percentages on my page but then the "a" elements overlap. I would like not to change "box-sizing: border-box;". I tried to find a solution on the internet but without success. Sorry for my English.
I've the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
      box-sizing: border-box; /* I would not like to change / delete it */
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      }

      body {
      text-align: center;
      }

      nav {
      background-color: black;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      }

      ul {
      list-style: none;
      }

      ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }

      ul li a {
      display: block;
      width: 200px; /* I would like to use % here! */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: red;
      border-radius: 25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dont use % on the links, use it on the `li`.

Comment: Also, consider using `calc()` to avoid overlapping: I mean, if an element is set to be `20%` wide, but it has margins or paddings, choose `calc(20% - foo)`; this is enough to avoid `border-box` and that’s what I do in these cases. If a browser doesn’t support it, just add Autoprefixer.

Comment: @Paulie_D After using % for `li`, the text inside the `a` elements overlaps

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
width:20%;
  }
```

Comment: Works, but now the text inside the "a" elements overlaps. (If this text is long enough)